# не все участники дискорд сервера добавляются в базу данных. Sqlite3 и Discrod.py

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

При разработке своего бота, я столкнулся с ошибкой

> cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)") sqlite3.OperationalError: near "anxiety": syntax error.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а так же, у меня на сервере 76 + людей, а в базу данных добавляются не все участники.
[image: База данных]

Вот код:

```html
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3
from config import settings

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'], intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT, 
        id TEXT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""")
    connection.commit()

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
                print(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', '{member.id}', 0, 0, 1)")
                connection.commit()

print('Бот готов к работе!')
```

Прошу о помощи.

Comment: можно код в студию? без него не представляю в чем может быть проблема

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедитесь что у вас включены интенты на сайте разработчика Discord.
2. Никогда не используйте `f` для SQL-запросов, это создает дырку в-вашей системе безопасности, вместо этого подставляйте значения.

Было:

```
if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
               cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
```

Стало:

```
if cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?", (member.id)).fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (f'{member}',member.id,0,0,1))
```

3. `''` - кавычки используются только для текстовых данных, смените `id` на `INT`, и уберите кавычки.
4. Уберите отсюда `print`, если хотите посмотреть что вносится в базу, проще написать:
   `print(member)`
   `print(member.id)`